# Why is foo->bar->foobar considered bad style? And how to avoid without adding code?

Tags: c++, pointers, coding-style

Our C++ professor mentioned that using the result of operator-> as input into another operator-> is considered bad style.

So instead of writing:

```
return edge->terminal->outgoing_edges[0];
```

He would prefer:

```
Node* terminal = edge->terminal;
return terminal->outgoing_edges[0];
```

1. Why is this considered bad style?
2. How could I restructure my program to avoid the 'bad style' but also avoid the extra line of code that is created as per the above suggestion?

Comment: I've never heard that one. The only benefit I can see is that if you get an error from a null pointer you can tell from the line number which dereference it was, and it's marginally easier to examine the intermediate pointer in a debugger. But if there was a danger of a null dereference you should explicitly check for it before the second line. No, I can't see a good reason.

Comment: It's easier to debug for one thing.  It's simpler to test if terminal is null.

Comment: Maybe because that will help when you have a dereferenced a null pointer and are trying to find out which one. This way when you understand the line of error (from a debugger for example) you'll know  which pointer it is)

Comment: [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) calls this the "Train Wreck" because each pointer looks like a train carriage coupled to the next one.

Comment: Personally, I'd be more inclined to say that fiddling with member variables directly is bad style and that both `terminal` and `outgoing_edges` should be acessors or appropriate method invocations. If you're not going to be all objecty about it, you may as well just be writing C!

Comment: I don't think the "law-of-demeter" tag is appropriate to the question, because the prof's preferred code is just as contrary to the law as the code it replaces. It's appropriate to the answer though: anyone know whether that's a good reason to keep it? Same goes for "decoupling", the prof's code is equally coupled as the `->` chain.

Comment: And you might get a better explanation out of the prof if you ask why stop there. Why not `Node *terminal = edge->terminal; Edge *out_edges = terminal->outgoing_edges; return out_edges[0];` ?

Comment: @SteveJessop I think he stops there because he doesn't like the result of an operator-> being used as the input into another operator-> which my second example avoids (although the result is still being used as input into an assignment operator!).

Comment: If he can explain why he doesn't like the result of `operator->` being used as the LHS of `operator->`, but he does like the result of `operator->` being used as the LHS of `operator[]`, then that might tell you what kind of objection it is -- someone can "not like" something for aesthetic reasons only; for reasons to do with reading/writing the code (e.g. line length); to avoid some simple typo that's easy in one case; to create a design constraint. You could also ask whether `auto terminal = ...` would be good or bad: maybe he *wants* you to have to look up the type `Node*` in the docs.

Comment: I see your point. Why make a distinction between `operator->` and `operator[]`? I don't have lectures with this prof anymore.. but if I see him around, I will ask him this very question!

Comment: And assuming all the types involved are pointer types, what about `return *(*(*edge).terminal).outgoing_edges;`? I mean, obviously that's bad, but is it bad for the same reason or for a different one :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should ask your professor as to why he considers it bad style. I don't. I would however consider his omission of the const in the declaration of terminal to be bad style.

For a single snippet like that, it's probably not bad style. However consider this:

```
void somefunc(Edge *edge)
{
   if (edge->terminal->outgoing_edges.size() > 5)
   {
        edge->terminal->outgoing_edges.rezize(10);
        edge->terminal->counter = 5;
   }
   ++edge->terminal->another_value;
}
```

This is starting to get unwieldy - it is difficult to read, it is difficult to write (I made approximately 10 typos when typing that). And it requires a lot of evaluation of the operator-> on those 2 classes. OK if the operator is trivial, but if the operator does anything exciting, it's going to end up doing a lot of work.

So there's 2 possible answers:

1. Maintanability
2. Efficiency

And a single snippet like that, you can't avoid the extra line. In something like the above, it'd have resulted in less typing.

Comment: With this code, I definitely see the benefit in declaring the pointer first because it's used multiple times in the same code block. As a general rule, if I 'use' something more than once in a code block I declare it as a variable, and this falls under that rule of thumb. So it seems that in my simple example it's probably not bad style. But if the code was any more complex, it would be.

Comment: Typo?  "edge->terminal-counter"

Comment: I rest my case! (though I see it's been editted to correct it)

Answer (score 19):

There's a number of reasons.

The [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) gives a structural reason (note that your C++ professors code still violates this though!). In your example, `edge` has to know about `terminal` and `outgoing_edges`.  That makes it tightly coupled.

As an alternative

```
class Edge {
 private:
   Node* terminal;
 public:
   Edges* outgoing_edges() {
      return terminal->outgoing_edges;
   }
}
```

Now you can change the implementation of `outgoing_edges` in one place without changing everywhere.  To be honest, I don't really buy this in the case of a data structure like a graph (it is tightly coupled, edges and nodes can't escape each other).  This'd be over-abstraction in my book.

There's the null dereference problem too, in the expression `a->b->c`, what if `b` is null?

Comment: The Law of Demeter certainly forbids chains of `->`, but it also forbids this professor's preferred form `Node* terminal = edge->terminal;`. This is probably a better reason than the prof's reason, though.

Comment: does this example still work if I change the 'Terminal' to a Node* as per my code example? (I edited). I don't see why it is less coupled though.. doesn't 'Edge' still 'know' about Node* and outgoing_edges[] in this example?

Comment: I think the Law of Demeter mainly applies to testability.  For more complex object graphs, when testing (e.g.) edge, it would be somewhat annoying to mock a complex `terminal` object to return a mocked `outgoing_edges` object.  It would be easier to just mock `getOutgoingEdges()`.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I can't be sure about what your professor did mean, bu I have some thoughts.

First of all, code like this can be "not-so-obvious":

```
someObjectPointer->foo()->bar()->foobar()
```

You can't realy say what is the result of `foo()`, and thus you can't really say on what is the `bar()` being called. Is that the same object? Or maybe its a temp object that is being created? Or maybe it's something else?

Another thing is if you have to repeat your code. Consider an example like this:

```
complexObject.somePart.someSubObject.sections[i].doSomething();
complexObject.somePart.someSubObject.sections[i].doSomethingElse();
complexObject.somePart.someSubObject.sections[i].doSomethingAgain();
complexObject.somePart.someSubObject.sections[i].andAgain();
```

Compare it with such:

```
section * sectionPtr = complexObject.somePart.someSubObject.sections[i];
sectionPtr->doSomething();
sectionPtr->doSomethingElse();
sectionPtr->doSomethingAgain();
sectionPtr->andAgain();
```

You can see how the second example is not only shorter, but easier to read.

Sometimes the chain of functions is easier, because you don't need to bother with what they return:

```
resultClass res = foo()->bar()->foobar()
```

vs

```
classA * a = foo();
classB * b = a->bar();
classC * c = b->foobar();
```

Another thing is debugging. It is very hard to debug long chains of function calls, because you simply can't understand which of them causes the error. In this case, breaking the chain helps a lot, not to mention you can do some extra checks too, like

```
classA * a = foo();
classB * b;
classC * c;
if(a)
   b = a->bar();
if(b)
   c = b->foobar();
```

So, to summarize, you can't say that it is a "bad" or "good" style in general. You have to consider your circumstances first.

Answer (score 3):

The two code snippets you have shown is (of course) semantically identical.  When it comes to matters of style, suggest you simply follow what your professor wants.

Slightly better than your second code snippet would be:

```
Node* terminal = (edge ? edge->terminal : NULL);
return (terminal ? terminal->outgoing_edges[0] : NULL);
```

I am assuming that outgoing_edges is an array; if not, you have to check for that being NULL or empty as well.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are necessarily better in their current form. However, if you were to add a check for null in your second example, then this would make sense.

```
if (edge != NULL)
{
   Node* terminal = edge->terminal;
   if (terminal != NULL) return terminal->outgoing_edges[0];
}
```

Though even that is still bad because who is to say that `outgoing_edges` is properly populated or allocated. A better bet would be to call a function called `outgoingEdges()` that does all that nice error checking for you and never causes you **undefined behavior**.